# How to set timeout for "Page should contain element" in Robot Framework / Selnium when using "Create Webdriver"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

I'm having an issue with the "Page should contain element" keyword in combination with the "Create webdriver" keyword.

For example, using the "Open browser" keyword, I open a browser, search for an item, then say "Page should contain element". In this case, the test case will wait x seconds, and only fail if the element is not there at that point.

However, if I open the browser using the "Create webdriver" keyword, the "Page should contain element" keyword will *not* wait x seconds, it fails immediately if the element is not there.

In case my method to open the browser is the issue, this is how I do it:

```
Open Chrome with extension
    ${ChromeOptions} =    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${ChromeOptions}    add_extension    ${EXECDIR}${/}ChroPath.crx
    ${Options}=    Call Method    ${ChromeOptions}    to_capabilities
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    desired_capabilities=${Options}
    Go to    ${ENV_URL}
```

I've double checked the timeouts by doing

```
    ${implicit}=    Get Selenium Implicit Wait
    ${speed}=    Get Selenium Speed
    ${timeout}=    Get Selenium Timeout
```

and the values returned are the same regardless of whether I have open browser or create webdriver.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

use below keyword it will wait for 30s maximum and every 5s verify the text is visible. (seconds are your choice, so you can modify as per your need)

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    30s    5s    Page Should Contain    ${text}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the keyword below from SeleniumLibrary, which will wait for a given time ${timeout} or until the page contains the element.

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    ${locator}    ${timeout}
```